# NgModal does not display in Angular project

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to display a modal on button click. The modal is in a dedicated component.

The modal is inside a component named NgbdModalContent and the modal is activated on button click by a method that is inside another component.

This is  NgbdModalContent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" 
 (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>"Some text"</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" 
  (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
      </div>
   `
 })
 export class NgbdModalContent {

   constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
 }
```

This is the method inside the other component:

```
    async onCreateClicked() {
   var  modalService=new NgbModal;
     const modalRef = modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    return;
   }
```

Now, this won't compile because new NgbModal requires some arguments and I don't know what to put in there and I can't put the NgbModal as constructor argument of this component because it already has another constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added code like below

```
constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
```

And when you create object of this like

```
var  modalService=new NgbModal;
```

-- It will always ask to pass arguments then. So If above parameter does not in use -remove that. And instead of creating Object with new, use constructor.

Comment: You mean I should use it like this: `constructor(private modalService: NgbModal)`  ?
The problem is that I already have another constructor and apparently I can't add another one.

Comment: If you already have constructor then add this into that. what's the problem?

Comment: I added it into the constructor, it works fine now, thanks

Comment: Thanks, If your problem solved please mark correct this answer to help other.